# I Need Help in Parsing an XML in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery

Can someone help me to parse the following XML in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005)?

```
<Tx>
    <T>1</T>
    <C>1</C>
    <T>2</T>
    <C>1</C>
    <T>3</T>
    <C>1</C>
    <T>4</T>
    <C>1</C>
</Tx>
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
        Tx.query('T').value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [Column 1],
        Tx.query('C').value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [Column 2]
    FROM @MyXml.nodes('Tx') x(Tx)
```

but it didn't work, as I get the following result:

```
Column 1    Column 2
--------    --------
1234        1111
```

while expecting (what I want to achieve):

```
Column 1    Column 2
--------    --------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
```

The string is obviously a valid XML, but is it valid for T-SQL?

I'll be grateful too if someone can provide a reference that explains how XML works in T-SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you want to match a `C` to a `T`. Does it matter what values are paired to each other or is it ok to just pick any value?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, sorry, but I didn't understand the question. I'm sending the XML to a Stored Procedure and from there I'm doing something like (after inserting the XML in a temp table): join the XML "table" with MyTable1 based on [Column 2] and insert [Column 1] in MyTable2... or `INSERT INTO MyTable2 (SomeColumn, SomeOtherColumn) SELECT A.[Column 2], B.AnotherColumn FROM @xmlTable A JOIN MyTable1 B ON A.[Column 1] = B.Id`

Comment: In your sample data the value for `C` is always `1`. Will there only ever be one distinct value for all C's in one XML?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, if it's always one distinct value I have no problem, right? :) the sample XML I gave is only a sample, but kinda say that `C` has very little distinct values comparing to `T`.

Comment: Do you want the first value of `T` to be paired with the first value of `C` and the second value of `T` to be paired with the second value of `C` etc, etc ....? Can there be more T's then C`s or more C´s than T´s? Can there be two or more consecutive T´s without a C in between or the other way around? It is possible to do a XQuery on `position` using a numbers table. I could provide an answer doing that but I would like to know the rules for pairing T`s and C`s. BTW, @marc-s is correct when he says that you should redesign your XML if you can.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, I agree; redesigning the XML is the best option if I can do so. Anyway, the number of `T`'s and `C`'s is always the same and it's always `T` then `C`... just think of the XML as if it was a table; you always have the two column in the same order in each row regadless of whether you have a value there or not. In my case it's even better; they always have values.

Comment: Then my first answer will work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to pair the values by position in. First T is matched against first C and so on.

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<Tx>
    <T>1</T>
    <C>4</C>
    <T>2</T>
    <C>3</C>
    <T>3</T>
    <C>2</C>
    <T>4</T>
    <C>1</C>
</Tx>'

select @XML.value('(/Tx/T[position() = sql:column("N.number")])[1]', 'int') as Column1,
       @XML.value('(/Tx/C[position() = sql:column("N.number")])[1]', 'int') as Column2
from master..spt_values as N
where N.type = 'P' and
      N.number between 1 and @XML.value('max((count(/Tx/T), count(/Tx/C)))', 'int')
```

With a different structure of the XML like [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053341/569436) by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) the query is **much** simpler.

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<Tx>
  <row>
    <T>1</T>
    <C>4</C>
  </row>
  <row>
    <T>2</T>
    <C>3</C>
  </row>
  <row>
    <T>3</T>
    <C>2</C>
  </row>
  <row>
    <T>4</T>
    <C>1</C>
  </row>
</Tx>'

select T.R.value('T[1]', 'int') as Column1,
       T.R.value('C[1]', 'int') as Column2
from @XML.nodes('/Tx/row') as T(R)
```

Comment: Getting the following errors when trying to run the first (the second one gives similar errors but different line #s)

Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@XML".

Comment: @JamesJiao - It's a syntax that works in SQL Server 2008. If you are using SQL Server 2005 you have to split the declaration of the variable `@XML` and the assignment into two statements like this `declare @XML xml; set @XML = 'xml goes here';`

Comment: I selected this as the answer to my question although I don't like how ugly the code can be to parse something simple... but if this is how it is then this is how it is. My advice is to have the XML formated like what Mikael Eriksson and marc_s suggested... when possible.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve??

Your current select statement will list out all the `<T>` elements below `<Tx>` - but only those - not the `<C>` nodes, too - and you seem to want to get the values from both kinds of subnodes - right??

This will give you all the elements from the `<T>` nodes - is that what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    Tx.x.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [Column 1]
FROM @MyXml.nodes('Tx/T') Tx(x)
```

This will give you all the elements from inside the `<Tx>` node, including their "type" (C or T) - is that what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    ColumType = Tx.x.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(10)'),
    ColumnValue = Tx.x.value('.', 'varchar(10)')
FROM @MyXml.nodes('Tx/*') Tx(x)
```

**Update:** as resources for learning how to use XQuery in SQL Server, I'd recommend

- [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491/SQL-Server-2005-XQuery-and-XML-DML---Part-1.htm)
- [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Your XML is not well suited to do what you're trying to do - there's nothing that "keeps together" the T and C element that obviously belong together - so there's really nothing XQuery can do to parse this the way you want it to.

If you had the XML something like this:

```
<Tx>
   <Pair>
      <T>....</T>
      <C>....</C>
   </Pair>
   <Pair>
      <T>....</T>
      <C>....</C>
   </Pair>
   ....
</Tx>
```

then you could get the list of `Tx/Pair` nodes and get the T and C elements from that XML fragment. But right now - all you can do is parse out all 8 subnodes of `<Tx>` and display their values - that's really all you can do

Comment: @TheBlueSky: you cannot parse it the way you want - there's no "structure" that keeps the corresponding `<T>` and `<C>` elements together - so there's nothing in XPath you can do to parse those elements as "column1" and "column2" as you want to.

Comment: yes, if I have the XML like your example, I would be a simple task, but, alas, it's not the case. Anyway, thanks for the references.

Comment: I'll vote up for this post as it has partially answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
select a.t, b.c
from
(
    select t.c.value('.[1]', 'int') [t]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.c) [rn]
    from @MyXml.nodes('Tx/T') t(c)
)a
join
(
    select t.c.value('.[1]', 'int') [c]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.c) [rn]
    from @MyXml.nodes('Tx/C') t(c)
)b on b.rn = a.rn
```

or another way:

```
select t.t [T]
    , @MyXml.value('(Tx/C[position() = sql:column("rn")])[1]', 'int') [C]
from
(
    select t.c.value('.[1]', 'int') [t]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.c) [rn]
    from @MyXml.nodes('Tx/T') t(c)
)t
```

Comment: this is only a workaround; do you mean T-SQL cannot parse the giving XML?

Comment: @TheBlueSky, As I know - nope.

Comment: Looks a *bit* suspicious to order by a `nodes` instance but apparently it uses a id from the XML Reader `<ColumnReference Table="[XML Reader with XPath filter]" Column="id" />`. Adam Machanic has bloged about this in [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx). +1